# Spring @Profile Annotation not working in tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have maven setting up environment variable for me

```
               <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <spring.active.profiles>development</spring.active.profiles>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
```

Then I have two profile classes

```
@Profile("development")
public class MockIfsClient implements IFSClient {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getPayload() {
        return "MockIFS";
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class RestIfsClient implements IFSClient {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getPayload() {
        return "REST IFS Client";
    }
}
```

and a manager

```
public class IFSManager {
    private IFSClient ifsClient;

    @Autowired
    public IFSManager(@Nonnull final IFSClient ifsClient) {
        this.ifsClient = ifsClient;
        System.out.println(ifsClient.getPayload());
    }
}
```

When I try to test this and see that the injected bean is `MockIFSClient`, it fails

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {IFSManager.class, MockIfsClient.class, RestIfsClient.class},loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class IFSManagerTest {
    @Autowired
    private IFSManager ifsManager;

    @Test
    public void testMockIfsClient() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Error I see is

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.IFSClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Nonnull(when=ALWAYS)}
```

I am newbie to Spring and not sure what wrong I am doing

**UPDATE**

If I remove `@Profile` annotation, it fails

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { IFSManager.class, RestIfsClient.class, MockIfsClient.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class IFSManagerTest {
    @Autowired
    private IFSManager ifsManager;

    @Test
    public void testMockIfsClient() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Active Profile: " + System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

with error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.IFSClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: restIfsClient,mockIfsClient
```

Comment: Your mock client isn't a configuration, and I don't see either a bean declaration or component-scanning anywhere. Make this work without the profiles first.

Comment: so yes it works if I remove the `@Profile` annotation, but always returns `MockIFS`

Comment: sorry, I was missing one class inclusion. I see different error now. Also, mockIFS and RestIFS are beans since they have @Component annotaiton

Comment: are you saying if you change the environment variable value to "production" you do not get the `RestIfsClient` injected and the `MockIfsClient` is injected irrespective of what profile value you specify ?

Comment: Please see the update, I see errors because there are 2 beans of type `IFSClient`, not how do I filter it using `@Profile` annotation? I have no idea. I thought putting `@Profile` on classes would do the magic, but its not the case it seems

Answer (score 3):

Try `spring.profiles.active` as your property name.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

```
@ComponentScan("your.base.package")
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Profile("development")
    public IFSClient mockIfsClient() {
       return new MockIfsClient();
    }

    @Profile("production")
    public IFSClient restIfsClient() {
       return new RestIfsClient();
    }

}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Configuration.class)
@ActiveProfile("development")
public class IFSManagerTest {

}
```

Aslo remove the class annotations on `RestIfsClient` and  `MockIfsClient`